# How to tell mount.nfs to use rpcbind v3 or v4, instead of the older v2 (ie. portmapper)?

Tags: nfs

I would like to force my NFSv3 client to use rpcbind v3 or V4 (as described in RFC 1833) when communicating with the rpcbind (formerly portmapper) remote server, but I neither found a mount.nfs option telling the client to do so, nor I found a solution googling the Net.
So I wonder if there is any way to do so...? Or is this restricted to NFSv4 mounts only?

For NFSv3, the available options related to versions are only to force NFS protocol version ("-o nfsvers" or "-o vers") or MOUNTd version ("-o mountvers").
But anyway, in any of my multiple attempts, mount.nfs uses v2 (as described in RFC 1833), i.e. the former portmapper to get program ports from the rpcbind service on remote port 111.

Thanks in advance

Comment: As far as I can see from the RFC rpcbind V3 and V4 just extend the set of internal API-calls, but not the underlying communication - which seems to be compatible to portmap. The new NFSv4 TCP-only connect does not use rpcbind at all - IMHO.

Comment: Thanks Nils, I confirm that v3/v4 extend the API, mainly to be able to return an IP address along the TCP/UDP port (simplifying), and this is what I'd like: that the mount.nfs retrieves the needed port using one of those versions, as the actual NFS & Mount servers are not located on the same box than the portmapper/rpcbind server.

As an example, when one uses "rpcinfo <serverIp>", this is v3 that is used, as shown by the output listing IPs along ports, while "rpcinfo -p <serverIP>" uses v2 and retrieves ports only.

Answer (score -1):

To mount NFS export from target server using NFSv3

mount –o v3 target_server_name:/export/share /mnt

hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not my point, as explained in my original post I'm looking for a way to set rpcbind version. In your sample above, this is the NFS version that is specified.